# Unset delegate is crashing

Tags: ios, swift

I have a viewcontroller that uses a delegate. The view is opening with an bar button item. And 'closed' on te back button or as a swipe back.

Unfortinatelly the code is crashing, I can't reproduce it myself but I have several crash reports. It is crashing on this line:

request.delegate = nil;

And I think it has to do that when the view opens again, the delegate is already nil, while that is not good I think?

This is my code (I have removed a lot of methods to make it more clear):

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase
import StoreKit

class Premium : UITableViewController, SKPaymentTransactionObserver, SKProductsRequestDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(onHasPayed(notification:)), name: .hasPayed, object: nil)


        if SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments() {
            print("starting IAPS")
            let productIdentifiers = Set([ audioWifi, audioVideo4G, deluxe])

            self.request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productIdentifiers as Set<String>)
            self.request.delegate = self
            self.request.start()


        } else {
            print("please enable IAPS")
        }
    }

    @objc func onHasPayed(notification: NSNotification) {
        redirect()
    }

    private func redirect(){
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate! as! AppDelegate

        let initialViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "hh")
        appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
        appDelegate.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }


    private var request: SKProductsRequest!


    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        request.delegate = nil;
        request.cancel()
        request = nil;

    }
}
```

Where do I need to set the request delegate, and where do I need to unset it? Because, I don't know what is going wrong as I can't simulate it myself.

Possible fix:

```
    private var request: SKProductsRequest?

    if SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments() {
                print("starting IAPS")
                let productIdentifiers = Set([ audioWifi, audioVideo4G, deluxe])

                self.request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productIdentifiers as Set<String>)
                self.request?.delegate = self
                self.request?.start()
            } else {
                print("please enable IAPS")
            }

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        if let req = request {
            req.delegate = nil;
            req.cancel()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `request` variable is an implicitly unwrapped optional, and you're not checking if it's `nil` in `viewWillDisappear(_:)` before reaching into it to clear the `delegate` property.

If the user's device is not set up to make payments (`SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()` returns `false`), you never set `request` to anything, and so it is `nil`. When you leave the view controller, `viewWillDisappear(_:)` unwraps `nil`, and it will crash.

This is a good example of why it is generally preferable to avoid implicitly unwrapped optionals. If your code used a regular optional, you'd unwrap it with an `if let` and skip the reset logic in `viewWillDisappear(_:)`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is a lot clearer now. I have edited my question with a "possible fix" do you want to check it? :)

Comment: Yes, that looks fine. You could test it by temporarily replacing the call to `SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()` with `false` and trying the scenario I described. It will crash without your fix, and be fine with it.

Comment: Okay, Thanks! One more question, is the place to nil the request the right place? Because viewdidload is not loading everytime right?

Comment: `viewDidLoad()` runs when the view controller first loads your view. This is usually, but not necessarily, immediately before the view controller is presented. So yep, just once. `viewWillDisappear(_:)`, on the other hand, is called anytime something else will be front-most. This _could_ be when the view controller dismisses, but it will also happen if something else is pushed onto a navigation controller or if your view controller presents a full-screen modal. So it could disappear, and then appear, several times before deallocation.

Comment: Okay, clear. But is setting the delegate nil at the viewWillDissapear the good place? Because I set it every time to nil as the view goes away. While it is not always set because viewdidload is not always called right?

Comment: Setting it to `nil` means you'll never get those callbacks if StoreKit is slow and you push something else onto a navigation stack. Practically speaking, that's probably not something to be terribly worried about. If you want to match up better with `viewDidLoad()`, I'd put the cancelation and `nil` set in `deinit`.